# Fedora 25 Broadcom Wireless BCM43228 No WiFi

Tags: fedora, wifi, networkmanager, broadcom

I know Broadcom does not play nice with Fedora, I've been dealing with this for several years and versions. In the past, installing kmod-wl or akmod-wl was usually enough to get everything up and running (after blacklisting b43 and b43 legacy and long time ago).

Details:

Lenovo Thinkpad Twist s230u

uname -r

```
4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64
```

lspci -vnn -d 14e4:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited Device [14e4:0607]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f1d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

rpm -qa | grep -e kernel -e broadcom-wl -e kmod-wl | sort

```
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.9.0-1.fc25.x86_64
akmod-wl-6.30.223.271-7.fc25.x86_64
broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271-1.fc24.noarch
kernel-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
kernel-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64
kernel-core-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
kernel-core-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64
kernel-debug-devel-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64
kernel-headers-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64
kernel-modules-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
kernel-modules-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64
kernel-modules-extra-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
kernel-modules-extra-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64
kmod-wl-6.30.223.271-7.fc25.x86_64
libreport-plugin-kerneloops-2.8.0-1.fc25.x86_64
```

I restarted Network Manager to no avail. Rebooted, no change.

ifconfig

```
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.170  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::dbf:6e57:4c52:2a14  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 20:89:84:d2:7b:2c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 274564  bytes 389721772 (371.6 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 73269  bytes 6440437 (6.1 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 192  bytes 14760 (14.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 192  bytes 14760 (14.4 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 52:54:00:e1:8a:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but iwconfig

```
virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

modprobe with any wl (akmod-wl; kmod-wl; broadcom-wl) I've used before returns:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ______ not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64`
```

When I installed using `dnf` did the modules end up in the wrong place? We're digging deeper into this and how Linux actually works that I've ever gone before. Is it an issue that the broadcom-wl ends in fc24.noarch in stead of fc25.something? Anything, please.

EDIT TO ADD

sudo akmods --force

```
Checking kmods exist for 4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64             [  OK  ]
Files needed for building modules against kernel
4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64 could not be found as the following directories are missing:
/usr/src/kernels/4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64/
/usr/lib/modules/4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64/build/Is the correct kernel-devel package installed?
```

EDIT TO ADD (2):
sudo dnf install kernel devel leads to this:

```
[Kennedy@Shield_Generator ~]$ sudo dnf install kernel-devel
[sudo] password for Kennedy: 
google-chrome                                    26 kB/s | 3.7 kB     00:00    
Fedora 25 - x86_64 - Updates                     18 MB/s |  17 MB     00:00    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:11 ago on Tue Jan 31 19:43:34 2017.
Package kernel-debug-devel-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package             Arch          Version                 Repository      Size
================================================================================
Skipping packages with conflicts:
(add '--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade):
 kernel-devel        x86_64        4.9.6-200.fc25          updates         11 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Skip  1 Package

Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

sudo akmods --force

```
[Kennedy@Shield_Generator ~]$ sudo akmods --force
Checking kmods exist for 4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64             [  OK  ]
Files needed for building modules against kernel
4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64 could not be found as the following
directories are missing:
/usr/src/kernels/4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64/
/usr/lib/modules/4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64/build/Is the correct kernel-devel package installed?                                                [FAILED]
```

sudo dnf install -y broadcom-wl kernel-devel

```
[Kennedy@Shield_Generator ~]$ sudo dnf install -y broadcom-wl kernel-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:44:34 ago on Tue Jan 31 19:43:34 2017.

Package broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271-1.fc24.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Package kernel-debug-devel-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Package kernel-debug-devel-4.9.6-200.fc25.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

So they're installed, but not found in the correct directories? Whisky Tango Foxtrot, over.

ETA (3)

$ rpm -qa | grep -e kernel-debug

```
[Kennedy@Shield_Generator ~]$ rpm -qa | grep -e kernel-debug
kernel-debug-devel-4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64
kernel-debug-devel-4.9.6-200.fc25.x86_64
```

rpm -qa | grep -e kernel-devel

```
[Kennedy@Shield_Generator ~]$ rpm -qa | grep -e kernel-devel
[Kennedy@Shield_Generator ~]$ 
[Kennedy@Shield_Generator ~]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue, I installed kernel-devel

```
sudo dnf install kernel-devel-4.9.6-200.fc25.x86_64
```

then I followed the same steps that Xenox mentioned in his answer and now wifi is working fine

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that correct kernel-devel is installed. If not, first install kernel-devel package. Note that kernel-devel is different than kernel-debug-devel.

I guess that you have already installed the akmods and getting error "Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64".
Run,

```
# akmods --force
# depmod -a
# modprobe wl
```

either as root or with sudo.

I was experiencing same issue as yours and above method solved my problem.

Comment: Done, not resolved, see additional info added in ETA (2).

Comment: Problem seems to be with kernel-devel. Please share output of: rpm -qa | grep -e kernel-debug

Comment: info added to post. Sorry it;s turning into a wall of text

Comment: I wish I could've given you credit for all your effort, but Amjad came up with it. Sorry you'll have to settle for my up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same problem, I've solved this way:

```
sudo dnf install -y https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install -y broadcom-wl kernel-devel
sudo akmods --force --kernel `uname -r` --akmod wl
sudo modprobe -a wl
```

Change de 'uname -r' for yours.

Answer (score 0):

Does your machine have UEFI enabled in BIOS? I just installed Fedora26 on my Lenovo machine that has BCM4352.  I went through all the same steps to no avail but saw someone mention turning off UEFI in an Ubuntu forum.  Once I turned off UEFI my wireless card was enabled as soon as the OS booted.

Comment: Please write you answer so it focuses on the solution.  Minimize irrelevant chatter about what you tried that failed, and how you found the solution (but, if you are copying an answer from somewhere, you must say so and identify the source by name and by link). Avoid asking questions within answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, in fedora 29 install bcm43228 drive with rpmfusion repo.

```
# view info
lspci | grep -i broadcom

# installing
dnf install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
dnf install akmods
dnf install kmod-wl # dependences including akmod-wl and broadcom-wl

# reboot
reboot
```